# Use of regex in lexical analysis

Tags: regex, parsing, compiler-construction, lexical-analysis

I am trying to understand the way bottom-up parsing is implemented.

I got it to the point where regular expressions are converted to NFAs and then to DFAs and how a DFA is represented as a two dimensional table.

The question is wouldn't that be a quite large table with everything in the alphabet listed in one side of it? Is it really the way it is supposed to be implemented?

The other question is as far as I know most languages have some Regex implementation out of the box. Can those Regex utilities be used as some ready implementation of lexical analysis part and then one can go on directly to make the a parse table out the output?

Comment: *Can those Regex utilities be used as some ready implementation of lexical analysis part*: sure, but DFAs are much faster than the common (backtracking) regex libs.

Comment: Regular expressions have nothing to do with parsing of any kind, whether bottom-up, top-down, left-to-right, or right-to-left. They are used in the scanner, not the parser. And the procedure whereby  an NFA and then a DFA are generated precedes both. It happens at compile time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to understand the way bottom-up parsing is implemented.

No you aren't. Your question is about lexical analysis. Nothing to do with parsing.

> I got it to the point where regular expressions are converted to NFAs and then to DFAs and how a DFA is represented as a two dimensional table.

Again this has nothing to do with parsing. It has little to do with actual lexical analysis either. It is a question about lexical analyzer *generation*. You are now two steps removed from your stated subject.

> The question is wouldn't that be a quite large table with everything in the alphabet listed in one side of it?

It would be as large as it needs to be to represent the DFA, which in turn depends on the rules you specify. Not a real question.

> Is it really the way it is supposed to be implemented?

There are lots of ways to represent a DFA. *flex(1)* provides three or four options, for example, each with a different space/time tradeoff. You would almost certainly start by implementing character classes, which would eliminate 'everything in the alphabet listed in one side of it' immediately.

> The other question is as far as I know most languages have some Regex implementation out of the box. Can those Regex utilities be used as some ready implementation of lexical analysis part and then one can go on directly to make the a parse table out the output?

1. Again, parsing has nothing to do with lexical analysis.
2. A DFA *already is* a 'ready implementation of lexical analysis'.
3. As per @Qtax's comment, a single DFA for the entire ruleset is a lot faster than a series of regular expressions. It is almost certainly more compact as well.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Compilers-Principles-Techniques-Tools-2nd/dp/0321486811

This is the book I am following. I would be happy if you could introduce a book which is about _actual_ parsing.

Comment: @Vahid The 'Green Dragon' book you've cited is about lexical analysis, *and* parsing, *and* semantic analysis, *and* code generation, *and* optimization, *and* register allocation, *and* flow analysis, and quite a few other things. Your *question* is about generating lexical analyzers.

Comment: I was after parsing actually. I just presupposed, from the book, that lexical analysis is some base for parsing. I assume I was wrong. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Then you should be looking at the section(s) on DPDAs and LALR parsers.